# GWT:how to display a popup at the poistion of the key pressed

Tags: gwt

I am trying to display a word suggestion list when ctl+space entered as in eclipse.
For that I need to know the location where user has entered ctrl+space so that i can display the suggestion list exact below to the word user just entered.

I see ways to get the mouse cursor position , But isnt there a way to get the keyboard button pressed position , 
I am writing inside textArea, I tried getCursor, but it gives me the no of word on which user entered ctrl+space. Not the location as per the Window.

Any idea

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reliable, accurate and cross-browser way to do it with TextArea.

You can experiment with a RichTextArea (you don't have to provide a toolbar for rich text features) and its `getFormatter().insertHTML()` method. It will insert a new HTML element at a cursor position. You can insert a list of suggested words, that you can style to look anyway you like, or you can insert an empty `div` and try to show a panel relative to it.

Or you can use a different UI approach. Create a panel with a fixed position relative to your TextArea and show your suggested words there - similar to the way good smartphone keyboards show suggested words just above the keyboard itself. Once your users realize that suggested words always show up in the same place, they may even like this design better.

Comment: thanks , but as u mentioned , it will give me the position of mouse. I want to know the position of the cursor with respect to browser , So that I can display my popup at the location where the cursor is blinking in the textarea , Just press ctrl+space in Eclipse .. u will see the suggestion List , this is what I am building