# GWT:How to get screen coordinates in TextArea?

Tags: gwt

I am using a GWT TextArea and when writing some words, I want to display a popup with the suggestions when the user presses CTRL+SPACE. At the Location of TextArea where user entered  CTRL+SPACE.

Is there a way .

Thanks

Comment: It's not clear which coordinates you want. Cursor? Caret? TextArea? If caret, you already asked this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24276764/gwthow-to-display-a-popup-at-the-poistion-of-the-key-pressed

Comment: the cursor ,want to display a popup exactly where the cursor is but Have to use GWT TextArea, cant use RichTextArea as the cursorIndex thing not working on RichTextArea , I tried the way tim mentioned here But It was giving wrong indexes ,So I just forget abt the colooring thing and back to TEXTAREA:stackoverflow.com/questions/12542522/how-to-get-cursor-position-or-location-from-richtextarea-in-gwt

Comment: the other way you mentioned that is to show popup relative to textArea, That was'nt get accepted by the client

Comment: or Is there a way I can get the LINE Number of the TextArea , I think I'll do some workaround with this

Answer (score 0):

You can use SuggestBox instead of TextArea

http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/SuggestBox.html

Comment: I am using TEXTAREA , not TextBox,suggestBox is totally something else than TextArea, user will be writing 100 of lines in this text area , which cannot be done in suggestBox

Answer (score 0):

You can create a suggestBox associated with the textarea.

```
    TextArea content = new TextArea();     
    MultiWordSuggestOracle suggestOracle = new MultiWordSuggestOracle();
    SuggestBox suggestBox = new SuggestBox(suggestOracle, content);
```